# JSON parsing when names are regexes (dates)

Tags: java, json, date

Apologies if the Topic title isn't accurate, I didn't really know how to express it (no pun intended).
I have to parse JSON with an structure similar to that below. There are several of these Date arrays in the file: each array is named with a date in the form yyyy-MM-dd, but I do not know exactly which dates will be in the file (so I can't extract the array by its name). How else could I get it?
I'm using [json.simple for Java](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to parse the files. I don't expect an answer telling me how to do it using that library specifically, but if anybody knows, that would be a bonus :)

```
"2011-05-15":[
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"AnahiHappyBDay",
        "name":"AnahiHappyBDay"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Puerto Ricans",
        "name":"Puerto Ricans"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Epic Movie",
        "name":"Epic Movie"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Lee Soonkyu",
        "name":"Lee Soonkyu"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"MC1123",
        "name":"MC1123"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Dominique Strauss-Kahn",
        "name":"Dominique Strauss-Kahn"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"WeLoveNickJonas",
        "name":"WeLoveNickJonas"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Ripper Stefan",
        "name":"Ripper Stefan"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Luc\u00eda P\u00e9rez",
        "name":"Luc\u00eda P\u00e9rez"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"DB5K",
        "name":"DB5K"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"WeSupportYouGomez",
        "name":"WeSupportYouGomez"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"LSnoAltasHoras",
        "name":"LSnoAltasHoras"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Azerbaijan",
        "name":"Azerbaijan"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Eurovision",
        "name":"Eurovision"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Derek Boogaard",
        "name":"Derek Boogaard"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Terry Wogan",
        "name":"Terry Wogan"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"FMI",
        "name":"FMI"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"WorldLovesSwift",
        "name":"WorldLovesSwift"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"WorldWarIV",
        "name":"WorldWarIV"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Jedward",
        "name":"Jedward"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"GAGA10MILLION",
        "name":"GAGA10MILLION"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Stefan Raab",
        "name":"Stefan Raab"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Manchester United Campe\u00f3n",
        "name":"Manchester United Campe\u00f3n"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Derek Mooney",
        "name":"Derek Mooney"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Chord Overstreet",
        "name":"Chord Overstreet"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"IMF",
        "name":"IMF"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Joe Buck",
        "name":"Joe Buck"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"\u0410\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0436\u0430\u043d",
        "name":"\u0410\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0436\u0430\u043d"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"Wango Tango",
        "name":"Wango Tango"
     },
     {
        "promoted_content":null,
        "events":null,
        "query":"AlwaysRihannaNavy",
        "name":"AlwaysRihannaNavy"
     }
  ],
```

Comment: > How else could I get it? I don't understand. Are you saying you have multiple json's in a file and you want to process each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, if I understand your question, but I assume you want a list of the date keys.

Parsering this with json.simple should result in a JSONObject which is an map, so it's `keySet()` method will give you what you need:

```
JSONObject<String, Object> obj = (JSONObject<String, Object>)JSONValue.parse(s);
for (String key in obj.keySet()) {
  // do something with key
}
```

Comment: Thanks, RoToRa. At first I got a reference saying that JSONObject doesn't take parameters, so I just removed the parameters like so:

     JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(s);
     for (String key in obj.keySet()) {
          // do something with key
     }

And it works perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not very understood what your mean…
However, I thinking I have a solution[Using GSON(a lib from Google)]
After watch your data, I think we can create a Class. like this

```
public class Foo{
  private Date date/* or ID ?*/;
  private List<Content> contents; //a class defined blow
  /* constructors and methods */
}

public class Content{
  private String promoted_content;// Or a class? I'm not sure, because I found all of them is null
  private String events;// same as promoted_content
  private String query;
  private String name;    
  /* constructors and methods */
}
```

Now, using gson parse your data. like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();//maybe you wanna read docs of gson for more detail
Foo foo = gson.fromjson(/*your data*/, Foo.class);
```

Here you know you got a object named Foo and you can get its values. I noticed that you said perhaps there are more than ONE "date" so we can create a new class contains List.

Comment: Hi Pikaurd
Originally I was using GSon, but the data I'm parsing has a lot of unnecessary elements and attributes. I didn't want to have to create large classes full of useless elements just to Gson could create objects of that class from the data. I'd rather parse it manually, even if it means more work in the end.
That said though, I do like the thought of Gson. Can it do "manual" parsing as well as marshalling/unmarshalling? (i.e. could I tell it to extract the object with key "xyz"?)

Comment: Hi Benji.You're right. If your work is extract specified data GSON is unnecessary. You said "I'm parsing has a lot of unnecessary elements and attributes." for this my solution is create a Object not contains unnecessary elements and attributes. e.g. You have a data ['date':[{a:1,b:2,c:#}]] and just 'a' is your needed. Create a class just have a attribute a, GSON will ignore data not declared in your class. Anyway json.simple has more efficient than GSON, and above is my opinion.